# Configurar VSCode como editor de git bash

Tags: vscode, git-bash

Estoy empezando con git bash y tengo problemas para configurar VSCode como editor de texto predeterminado. He probado:

- Seleccionarlo en la instalación como predeterminado (y nada)
- Seleccionar en la instalación otro editor y poner el path de VSCode (y nada)
- Todas las opciones que en encontrado en StackOverflow relacionadas con el core.editor (incluidas las de cambiar la variable vim) y nada.

Dejo los mensajes de error que me da, por si a alguien le ha pasado y sabe como solucionarlo.

```
ssmgeo@LAPTOP-9JV6L4AB MINGW64 ~
$ git config --global core.editor "code --wait"

ssmgeo@LAPTOP-9JV6L4AB MINGW64 ~
$ code .
bash: code: command not found

ssmgeo@LAPTOP-9JV6L4AB MINGW64 ~
$ git config --global -e
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: line 1: code: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.

ssmgeo@LAPTOP-9JV6L4AB MINGW64 ~
$ code --help
bash: code: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día amigo, yo tuve el mismo problema y era por que estaba instalando VSCode descargando el instalador universal desde la pagina 'https://code.visualstudio.com/' pero desinstale ese para luego instalarlo con brew y quedo perfecto!
Aquí dejo el comando que encontré en la pagina de Homebrew para ejecutar en la terminal:
'brew install --cask visual-studio-code'

[image: Imagen de los comandos en la terminal]